# Autocomplete textbox in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, autocomplete, textbox

I have a database containing table value values as:

Database: staff_details

```
    staffname

    Arun
    Suresh
    Ankita
    Tina
```

I wish to autocomplete textbox with values from database. For example, If I enter 'a' in textbox, then it should display all names from databse starting with letter 'a' only. Now it is displaying all names that contain 'a' letter. 
ie
 If I type 'a' in textbox, the list should contain 'Anikta' and 'Arun' only.

My current list contain Arun,Anikta and Tina , when I enter letter 'a' in textbox.

How to display values from database starting with entered letter in textbox as a list

What I have tried:

```
          <label for="validationDefaultUsername">Authors </label>     
           <% 
           Connection con=null;                
           con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");    

           PreparedStatement ps1= con.prepareStatement("select staffname from staff_details ");              
           ResultSet rs=ps1.executeQuery();           
           %>      
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="prepared_by" id="auth" placeholder="Author " list="a_data" id="auth"   required>
          <%

           %>      
          <datalist id="a_data">
               <%while(rs.next())
                    { %>                   
                        <option value="<%= rs.getString(1) %> "> </option>
                        <%
                    }
                    %>
          </datalist>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)** operator in your query ,So your code will be like below :

```
        <% 
           Connection con=null;                
           con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");    

           PreparedStatement ps1= con.prepareStatement("select staffname from staff_details where staffname  LIKE ? ");  
            ps1.setString(1, search + "%");
                           //^ passing value to placeholder  & here "%"<- can be any letter   
           ResultSet rs=ps1.executeQuery();           
           %>
```

Also , refer my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391606/autocomplete-using-jsp-and-scripletsnot-using-java-classes/56393099#56393099) for doing this with ajax .

Comment: Error occur for ps1.setString(1, search + "%");

Comment: Refer my answer , to see how to do that

Comment: I have referedd your answer using ajax and jquery . But it is not invoking" List.jsp" .

Comment: How to use in datatable?